# Angular ng-repeat to generate Foundation tabs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a hard time using ng-repeat with Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/) tabs.

This displays tabs as I expect to see them, three across, evenly spaced.

```
<dl class="tabs three-up">
  <dd class="active"><a href="#a">A</a></dd>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#a">A</a></dd>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#a">A</a></dd>
</dl>
```

When I use ng-repeat to generate the tabs as below, the tabs no longer sit side by side, but each tab takes up the entire width, stacked on top of each other.

```
<dl ng-repeat="foo in foos" class="tabs three-up">
  <dd><a href="#/foos/{{foo.id}}">{{foo.name}}</a></dd>
</dl>
```

How can I render the tabs when they are generated in ng-repeat?

Comment: can u share the jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the ng-repeat on the "dd"

```
<dl class="tabs three-up">
  <dd ng-repeat="foo in foos"><a href="#/foos/{{foo.id}}">{{foo.name}}</a></dd>
</dl>
```